# How rename batch subdirectories in delphi?

Tags: delphi

I have hundreds of subdirectories in a folder and there are hundreds of subfolders in subdirectories. I want to check if the subfolder name include '(number)', if the subfolder contains it, I want to prefix '(number)' as the subfolder name: For example:

```
rootfolder
       --- subfolder1
                 ---subfolder11(100082)
                        --- file1.txt
        --- subfolder2(100083)
                  ---subfolder22(100085)
                         --- file2.txt 
                         --- subfolder222
                                     ---subfolder2222(80001)
                                                        ---file3.txt
```

I want to have:

```
rootfolder
       --- subfolder1
                 ---(100082)subfolder11
                        --- file1.txt
        --- (100083)subfolder2
                  ---(100085)subfolder22
                         --- file2.txt 
                         --- subfolder222
                                    --- (80001)subfolder2222
                                                        --- file3.txt
```

Can you help me?
Thanks a lot in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a code that renames subdirectories, customize it for your needs:

```
procedure ProcessDir(const DirName: string);
var
  Path, NextDir: string;
  F: TSearchRec;

begin
  Path:= DirName + '/*.*';
  if FindFirst(Path, faAnyFile, F) = 0 then begin
    try
      repeat
        if (F.Attr and faDirectory <> 0) then begin
          if (F.Name <> '.') and (F.Name <> '..') then begin
            NextDir:= DirName + '/' + F.Name;
            ProcessDir(NextDir);
// generate new folder name here, next line just for testing
            RenameFile(NextDir, NextDir + '_Renamed');
          end;
        end;
      until FindNext(F) <> 0;
    finally
      FindClose(F);
    end;
  end;
end;
```

Comment: Thanks so much for your code. It works fine and easily understood. I was originally stuck at how to iterate subfolders and incorrectly rename from top to deep.

Answer (score 3):

Well, as an example, this is my extract that does nasty things to folder trees - it does not rename them, it destroys them:

```
procedure splatDirectory(const dirSpec:string);
var searchRec:TsearchRec;
    searchResult:integer;
begin
  searchResult:=findFirst(dirSpec+'\*.*',faDirectory,searchRec);
  try
    while (0=searchResult) do
    begin
      if ((searchRec.attr and faDirectory)>0) then
      begin
        if (searchRec.name<>'.') and (searchRec.name<>'..') then
          splatDirectory(dirSpec+'\'+searchRec.Name)
      end
      else
        deleteFile(dirSpec+'\'+searchRec.Name);
      searchResult:=findNext(searchRec);
    end;
  finally
    findClose(searchRec);
  end;
  removeDir(dirSpec);
end;
```

This does work - copied from working code.

Comment: .. and it's 'bottoms-up' - the removeDir() is called just before exit & so the lowest folder in any branch is deleted first.  Just replacing this with a 'rename' and removing the code that deletes 'ordinary' files might work...

Comment: +1 odd downvote I have to say. Perhaps someone did not like that Yoda conditional!!

Comment: *while (0=searchResult)*, whaaat? camelCase? Did you write something in C?

Comment: Yoda conditionals - OK some don't like them.  I think that I started using them when I realised that I could look up at the name of the variable I needed in the foreground while some backgound thread in my brain is typing '0=' :)  The camelCase - don't know, lost in the mists of time..  Oh, and yes, my C/C++ looks just as bad..

Comment: *Good FORTRAN programmer can write FORTRAN in any language* :)

Comment: @martin nothing at all wrong with Yoda conditionals or camel case. Don't feel the need to apologise for either of those. Also `i` and `j` are excellent choices for loop vars. Don't understand the FORTRAN reference. I can see recursion here and variables with automatic storage!

Comment: Actually, C style hurts Pascal code quality very much. Yoda style destined to defeat specific pitfall which simply does not exist in Pascal.

Comment: The most important aspect of style is consistentency. OK, you have have indentation, decent variable names etc. So, the most important guideline is to be both consistent and sane. So long as it is consistent and sane and everyone on the team follows the same rules, it's fine. If camel case provokes outrage then that is a sign of unhealthy inflexibility. I personally use Pascal case, I don't write Yoda conditionals and I have different views on use and layout of begin/end. But I understand that others find my style odd and I absolutely respect the validity of opinions and views regarding style.

Comment: @MartinJames, i believe what David in the fact contradicts some (or all) my points as the follow-up to our previous disagreement. You can ignore us, and i beg your pardon for being disturbance here.

Comment: No apologies necessary. It would be very boring here if there was not the occasional disagreement, even though I'm always right :)

Comment: ..and, just to annoy purists some more, I use hungarian-type notation for components - 'foMainForm', 'tvFolders', 'meLog', 'edHostName'.

Comment: @Martin Thank you so much for your post, I tested your code, it works perfectly. But I have to pick only one as answer. This is not fair. I am your fan though I can not pick yours as answer.

Answer (score 1):

You need a recursive directory search to find all of the folders. And rename them, from the bottom-up.

Comment: If you use `FindFirst`/`FindNext` then does it matter whether or not you rename from bottom-up or top-down?

Comment: @DavidHeffernan - haven't tried this, (or thought about it deeply), but it seems to me that renaming from the top-down would generate invalid paths during the recursion?

Comment: @Martin It all depends on how `FindFirst`/`FindNext` work. They could be implemented to be resilient to objects being renamed during iteration. In fact if they were not so implemented then it would make them much less useful.